# Android Studio: how and where to provide ResourceBundles?

Tags: android

I am in the process of migrating an Android application that I had written years ago (back then using Eclipse) to AndroidStudio. I got the stuff building and executing by now but now I am at the next hurdle:
My code uses java.util.ResouceBundles to provide language specific messages and texts (e.g. button labels, column headers, menu texts).

After I moved the stuff to AS I have tried to move that stuff around but didn't succeed.
All I ever get is:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at mmo.myapplication.Messages.getString(Messages.java:21)
 ...
     Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name mmo.myapplication.messages, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException
```

ResourceBundles used to be a really simple and easy mechanism.
How does Android (and/or AS) handle ResourceBundles (or their equivalent) these days?
Where do these files have to be placed?
Do I need to adjust anything in the gradle setup to get these deployed with the application?

Comment: You need to place them at ```src > main > res > values > strings.xml```.

Answer (score 0):

As I just found out: the "normal" .../src/main/resources folder is the location to put them. That "res" folder that Android uses for its resources, confused me...